# How to use AsyncTask with xml Sax Parser?

Tags: android

I used xml sax parser to read xml from web and it works within android 2.3.
But now I want it to work on Android 3.0 to.
Because I read the file in the main thread I get the error:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

I tried to use AsyncTask but I could not make it to work.
Please tell me how to implement AsyncTask in my case. Here is my original code:

```
ListView lw = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
lw.setAdapter(aa);

try {
        /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
        URL url = new URL("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml");
        //aded to verify link
        URI uri = new URI(url.toString());
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200) {
           url = new URL("http://www.visual-efx.net/nbrfxrates.xml");
        }
        //aded to verify link
        /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
        ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);

        /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        /* Parsing has finished. */

        for (int i=1; i<=31; i++){
           list.add(myExampleHandler.valuta[i] + " = " + myExampleHandler.pret[i] + " lei");
           aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

} catch (Exception e) {
        /* Display any Error to the GUI. */
        Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Error", e);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 2):

You should actually use an [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) in this case. It'll make things easier. Just create your own class that extends AsyncTaskLoader and just have it have a single method, `loadInBackground()`. In your `loadInBackground()` method, put the code that you use to parse the xml like this:

```
public List<String> loadInBackground(){
  ArrayList toReturn = new ArrayList<String>();

  try {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml");

    URI uri = new URI(url.toString());
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200) {
       url = new URL("http://www.visual-efx.net/nbrfxrates.xml")
    }
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();


    XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

    ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
    xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);


    xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));


    for (int i=1; i<=31; i++){
      toReturn.add(myExampleHandler.valuta[i] + " = " + myExampleHandler.pret[i] + " lei");
    }

  } catch (Exception e) {

    Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG, "Error", e);
  }

  return toReturn;
}
```

Then, in the activity where you're displaying the list, have your Activity implement the [LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html) interface, like this

```
public YourActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<String>>
```

Then implement the callback methods. For instance, your `onLoadFinished()` method would look simply like this:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<String>>, List<String> data){
   aa.setData(data);
}
```

For more information on loaders, checkout [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html). Note that if you're targeting an API less than 3.0 you'll need to use the [Android Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can't get it to work.
My program consists in two classes.
1. The main activity : public class MainParser extends Activity{...my code here...}
2. An handler for the Sax parser: public class ExampleHandler extends DefaultHandler{...}

The code I posted belongs to the first activity and it is located inside public void onCreate(Bundle icile){.....} .

Can you explain more explicit how to do this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: So I can target my response, what exactly is not working for you. Is there something specific you aren't understanding?

Comment: I don't know where to implement the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks interface (is it in my main activity class? ).I tried my main activity (like this: public class MainParser extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<String>>) but I get an error: "LoaderManager cannot be resolved to a type" . Where do I implement the callback methods? Sorry for all the questions but I am new to Android and Java. Thanks alot!

Comment: That's the correct place to implement it. You just need to make sure you import the LoaderManager at the top of your file. And like I said, if you're targeting an API level less than 11, you'll need to download and install the Android Support Package and use the LoaderManager class from the support package.

Comment: I am using API level 12, but in the Manifest I put min sdk 9 so that my previous code will work, I will change that and see how it works. Thanks again

Comment: Ok, so I got to the point that I need to populate my listview. I am working at public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<String>> arg0, List<String> data){}. It gave me an error before I put "arg0" in there. I can't figure it out how to put the data loadedInBackground in my array list in my main activity class. Actualy I need to replace the list.add(".." + ".."); aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
with someting in the onLoadFinished but I don't know hot. Please help me..... again..